# Creating an arraylist in Scala

Tags: scala, arraylist

I am a teachers assistant for a class that teaches Scala. As an assignment, I want the students to implement an arraylist class.

In java I wrote it like:

```
public class ArrayList<T> implements List<T>{....}
```

Is there any equivalent List trait that I should use to implement the arraylist?

Answer (score 3):

The name *ArrayList* suggests that you should mix-in *IndexedSeq*. Actually you probably want to get all the goodies that are provided by *IndexedSeqLike*, i.e.

```
class ArrayList[A] extends IndexedSeq[A] with IndexedSeqLike[A, ArrayList[A]]
```

This gets you concrete implementations of *head*, *tail*, *take*, *drop*, *filter*, etc. If you also want *map*, *flatMap*, etc. (all the methods that take a type parameter) to work properly (return an *ArrayList[A]*), you also have to provide a type class instance for *CanBuildFrom* in your companion object, e.g.

```
def cbf[A, B] = new CanBuildFrom[ArrayList[A], B, ArrayList[B]] {
  // TODO Implementation!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The scala collection library is very complex. For an overview on the inheritance take a look at these pictures:

scala.collection.immutable: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.immutable.png

scala.collection.mutable: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.mutable.png

Also the scaladoc gives a good overview about all the classes and traits of the collection library.

Be aware, that in Scala a List is a real list, meaning it is a LinearSeq, in Java a List is more like an IndexedSeq in Scala.

Comment: I think Scala ArrayBuffers behave like Java ArrayLists.

Comment: `Vector` in Scala is an immutable tree implementation of `IndexedSeq`; Java's `List` interface is like Scala's `Seq` trait

Answer (score 1):

In Scala there are many Interfaces. First, they are separated in mutable and immutable ones. In Java ArrayList is based on an array - thus it is an indexed sequence. In Scala the interface for this is `IndexedSeq[A]`. Because ArrayList is also mutable, you can choose `scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq` otherwise `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq`. Instead of mutable.IndexedSeq you can also choose `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer`, which does not guarantee an access time of O(1).

If you wanna have a more functional approach you can prefer `Seq[A]` as interface or `Iterable[A]` if you want to be able to implement more than Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

That would be `Seq[T]`, or maybe `IndexedSeq[T]` - or even `List[T]`.